# How to separate the photoshopped part from the rest of the image if the original image is given?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on a project to detect spliced(photoshopped) images and want 128x128 patches at the boundaries of the forged regions. I have the authentic background image and the forged one.

If I simply find difference in pixel values and apply a threshold to get the binary image, I get a lot of noise(small black patches in the white part and vice versa) which doesn't get effectively removed by `cv2.medianBlur()`.
I'm assuming that this is because of different compression factors of the images before and after splicing. Also, some pixels in the spliced part are similar to the corresponding pixels in the auth. image.

So I replace the normal `cv2.threshold()` function which adds the values of 4-connected neighbours of the pixel and compares that with a threshold value.

This is my threshold function :

```
def threshold(image,thresh):
    b,g,r= cv2.split(image)
    res=np.zeros(b.shape,dtype=np.uint8)

    #Not considering boundary pixels for the binary image
    for i in range(1,b.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(1,b.shape[1]-1):
            sumb = b[i][j] + b[i+1][j] + b[i-1][j] + b[i][j+1] + b[i][j-1] 
            sumg = g[i][j] + g[i+1][j] + g[i-1][j] + g[i][j+1] + g[i][j-1] 
            sumr = r[i][j] + r[i+1][j] + r[i-1][j] + r[i][j+1] + r[i][j-1] 

            res[i][j]=255 if sumb<=5*thresh or sumg<=5*thresh or sumr<=5*thresh else 0

    res=res[1:-1,1:-1]
    res=cv2.copyMakeBorder(res,1,1,1,1,cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)
    return res
```

This does give better results but not as good as expected.

For example, this is an authentic image:

[image: original]

This is the spliced image:

[image: spliced]

This is the thresholded image (I found that `thresh=2` was the optimal value):

[image: thresholded]

I tried to remove small components by removing components with few white pixels using `connectedComponentsWithStats()`.

These are the borders after removing small connected components:

[image: borders]

while the expected image is:

[image: expected]

I could increase the minimum number of pixels required for each component but there are images in my dataset where the forged part is small.

How can I get better results than this?

Also, is it possible to optimize my `threshold` function? Right now it takes at least 2 seconds to process one image!

Comment: Interesting paper by Dr Neal Krawetz on photo forgery here... https://www.hackerfactor.com/papers/bh-usa-07-krawetz-wp.pdf

Comment: JPEG (i.e. lossy/noise-introducing image compression is probably making this more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I don't have OpenCV installed on my computed right now, so looked at your images in MATLAB instead. The Python code below is not tested.]

Because your images are identical except where purposeful changes were made (there is no scaling or translations to take into account), one can simply subtract the two images and look at the difference:

```
res = cv2.absdiff(image,thresh)
```

If you display this (with some contrast stretch) you'll see:

[image: absolute difference between the two images]

As you can see, at least one of the channels has a strong difference in the "spliced" region, outside of it here are some very light dots, caused by the lossy compression.

Let's take the maximum over R, G, B for each pixel:

```
res = np.amax(res, axis=2)   # (I think OpenCV stores the channels in the 3rd dimension?)
```

I found that most of the compression artefacts are below 15, so let's threshold there:

```
res = res > 15
```

Finally, apply your `cv2.medianBlur()` to remove the last bits of noise. You could also try applying `GaussianBlur()` before the threshold.

Comment: Your 3 lines of code worked like magic! I had tried the same thing in a very non-pythonic way -  checking if each channel value for each pixel was greater than 15 (using nested for loops). I don't think I got the same output. Some mistake with my logic, probably.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's still a problem with a few images that have only the sky background changed. The absolute difference is not much in these cases. How can I consider the neighbouring pixels to make it better without going through loops again?

Comment: @AbdulMuizz: You consider neighboring pixels using a filter. I would suggest `GaussianBlur`, then you can probably lower the threshold.